# How can one drawing a mirror image of an inductor in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw the mirror image of an inductor in TikZ so that if the devices is drawn horizontally then the bumps are on the lower side rather than the upper side. Does someone have an idea of how this could be done? Help would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 3):

You can just reverse the coordinates:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
    \draw (0,0) to [inductor] (2,0);      %% here draw from left to right
    \draw (2,-1) to [inductor] (0,-1);    %% here draw from right to left
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also rotate the inductors:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every inductor/.style={rotate=180},circuit ee IEC]
    \draw (0,0) to [inductor] (2,0);
    \draw (2,-1) to [inductor] (0,-1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Harish Kumar. I appreciate your quick response and your elegant solutions to my problem. Cheers!